# Get extension key inside of post processor

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

How can I fetch the extension key in my post processor?

I tried it like this like suggested [here](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-german/2011-March/076936.html)

```
 public function returnExtkey() {
     return t3lib_div::camelCaseToLowerCaseUnderscored($this->extensionName);
 }
```

However, I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'MyCompany\MyExtension\PostProcess\t3lib_div' not found
```

I also tried to call it without the function **camelCaseToLowerCaseUnderscored**:

```
echo "EXTNAME = '".$this->extensionName."'";
```

But I get an empty string as result.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I think I will just read it out from `ext_emconf.php`, it seems like there is no way to read out the extension key inside a controller in typo3-6.2.x

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to ask the request object for the extension key:

`$extName = $this->request->getControllerExtensionKey()`

by the way: `t3lib_div` was replaced by `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it but i get `Fatal error: Call to a member function getControllerExtensionKey() on null`. I use it in a post processor btw. i was not sure if this counts as controller. Is your function also working in a post processor?

Comment: Why do you need your own extensionKey? "By default" the extensionKey sould not changed? Maybe if I know the "why" I found another solution.

Comment: Oh wait, I made a mistake, of course I had to use my own request object...
However, now I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined method TYPO3\CMS\Form\Request::getControllerExtensionKey()`.
I need the extension key to read out the configuration settings of the extension. I forgot to mention that I am using Typo3 v6.2.25

Comment: I think the use of a post processor is important to solve this question. so I recommand to edit your question and describe more what you are doing and what you want to do.

Comment: I thought there is a global typo3 function to read out the extension name. However, I solved it setting the extension key manually.